# How to move all commits from a branch to another?

Tags: git

The scenario is this:

```
X1--X2--X3--X4--X5--X6 (master)
             \
              D1--D2--D3 (dev)
                       \
                        B1--B2--B3 (bug1)
```

I want to move all commits from *bug1* branch to master branch and get rid of bug1 branch. In this case:

```
X1--X2--X3--X4--X5--X6--B1--B2--B3 (master)
             \
              D1--D2--D3 (dev)
```

What's the best option to do this?

Comment: +1 For great ASCII art and a clear question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be a classic case of [`git rebase --onto`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase)

```
git rebase --onto master dev bug1
git checkout master
git merge bug1 # fast-forward merge
```

See also the [ProGit Book](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html) for another example of `rebase --onto`.