# push a branch with pre-req to github

Tags: git, bazaar, github-api, prerequisites

Say, from my original master, I made certain change to it and committed the change at time `t1` I then pushed this to github (calling it `branchA`). Then I made some other change and committed it at time `t2`. I don't want to push this to `branchA`, but I want to push it to another branch called `branchB`.

Is it possible to list `branchA` as the prerequisite for `branchB` so that when I do a pull request, the diff in `branchB` does NOT include the changes committed prio to `t1`, in other words, the diff  in `branchB` should only show the diff between `branchA` and `branchB`?

`Bazaar/Launchpad` offers this option, but I haven't been able to find the similar feature in `Github`. (I'm new to `git`, so maybe this isn't something they do in `Github`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have:

```
Local Repo                  Upstream (GitHub Repo)

 .--.--o--x--y branchA   <====> o--o--x branchA
(master)
```

But you want:

```
.--.--o--x branchA      <====> o--o--x branchA
(mast) \
        y branchB        => you can push now
```

That means you need first to rebase onto `o` what comes after `x` (`t1`) in order to build `branchB` *locally*, before pushing it to your fork.

```
git checkout branchA                
git branch branchB                  # creates branchB where branchA currently is
git reset --hard origin/branchA     # reset branchA to x
git rebase --onto master x branchB
```

Comment: To to clarify, if I do this, when my `branchA` gets merged to `master`, the diff on `branchB` and `master` would now be the same as the diff that's been shown there in `branchB` ?

Comment: @user1508893 yes: you are rebasing that diff to master in order to isolate it in its own branch.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. (Is this something that you know because you have experience with `git` or is there some documentations on this kind of stuff?)

Comment: @user1508893 I do have quite a bot of experience with git (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers), and have used `git rebase --onto` as well (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504917/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9192637/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13400050/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309)